# Reconexión con Oracle_cx

Tags: python, oracle-11g

Estoy utilizando el módulo que Oracle escribió para conectarse a sus BD desde python: [cx_Oracle](https://pypi.org/project/cx_Oracle/#description).

El caso es que no parece tener medios nativos para auto-reconectarse en caso de que perdiese la conexión por cualquier motivo.

Es por eso que estaba escribiendo un script simple para una sola sesión:

```
import cx_Oracle
import time

user = 'myuser'
psw = 'admin'
host = '165.45.12.1'
name = 'db'
table = "mytabla"

con = None
cursor = None

try:

    con, cursor = reconectar(con, cursor, user, psw, host, name)

    while True:

        if cursor is not None:
            try:
                query = f'SELECT * FROM {table}'
                cursor.execute(query)
                result = cursor.fetchall()
                print(result)
                print(con)
                print(cursor)
            except (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, cx_Oracle.InterfaceError) as ex:
                print(f'Excepcion: {ex}')
                print(con)
                print(cursor)
                error, = ex.args
                if error.code == 3135:
                    con, cursor = reconectar(con, cursor, user, psw, host, name)

        time.sleep(20)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit(0)
```

Donde mi función `reconectar` es:

```
def reconectar(con, cursor, user, psw, host, name):

    try:
        cursor.close()
    except Exception:
        print("Cursor ya cerrado")

    try:
        con.close()
    except Exception:
        print("Conexión ya cerrada")

    try:
        con = cx_Oracle.connect(user+'/'+psw+'@'+host+'/'+name)
    except Exception:
        print("Fallo al conectar")
        con = None

    try:
        cursor = con.cursor()
    except Exception:
        print("Fallo al crear cursor")
        cursor = None

    return con, cursor
```

En estos momentos estoy controlando el error `3151 - la conexión ha perdido contacto`. Sin embargo hay muchos más motivos de des-conexión que podría no estar controlando. En la [documentación](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) no veo ningún método o variable que me diga si el objeto conexión está conectado en ese instante.

Este es el output de tres iteraciones comentadas. Los objetos `cursor` y `connection` no cambian "exteriormente" a pesar de la des-conexión.

```
Cursor ya cerrado
Conexión ya cerrada
# Primera iteración satisfactoria
[(2, 5, 5, 5, 2, 10, 3, 3, 30, 10, 30, 60, 30, 30, 30, 30, 10.0)]
<cx_Oracle.Connection to myuser@165.45.12.1/db>
<cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to myuser@165.45.12.1/db>>
# Segunda iteración con puerto de BD bloqueado para simular pérdida de conexión
Excepcion: ORA-03135: la conexión ha perdido contacto
Identificador de Proceso: 0
Identificador de Sesión: 842 Número de Serie: 98425
# Tercera iteración tras reconectarse en otro puerto
<cx_Oracle.Connection to myuser@165.45.12.1/db>
<cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to myuser@165.45.12.1/db>>
[(2, 5, 5, 5, 2, 10, 3, 3, 30, 10, 30, 60, 30, 30, 30, 30, 10.0)]
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo comprobar si la conexión sigue viva para no re-conectarla en caso de que el error atrapado no sea mortal para la conexión?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Indagaciones

La [documentación de cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io) revela la existencia de un método [`Connection.ping()`](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html#Connection.ping) que parece que podría servir para probar el estado de salud de la conexión. Lamentablemente la documentación no da ningún detalle adicional sobre qué es retornado por esta función y los experimentos del usuario obtienen `None` como respuesta, lo que podría también interpretarse como que la función es asíncrona y retorna inmediatamente, siendo necesario en ese caso pasarle algún *callback*. La documentación no da detalles.

Por suerte, cuando los proyectos son *open source*, si la documentación no es muy buena siempre queda el recurso de leer directamente el código fuente.

En el caso de `cx_Oracle`, la implementación es en C, usando la API de python para [construir extensiones python en C](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html), lo que hace un poco más difícil su lectura.

En concreto, la función `ping()` está implementada [en la línea 1402 de `cxoConnection.c`](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/fc3450d48ad923cac781618dfd47431c9e1e34f6/src/cxoConnection.c#L1402), y dice así:

```
static PyObject *cxoConnection_ping(cxoConnection *conn, PyObject* args)
{
    int status;

    if (cxoConnection_isConnected(conn) < 0)
        return NULL;
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    status = dpiConn_ping(conn->handle);
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
    if (status < 0)
        return cxoError_raiseAndReturnNull();

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Vemos que comienza por testear si la conexión sigue viva (`cxoConnection_isConnected()`) y retorna `NULL` en caso contrario, lo cual es el patrón típico que indica que la propia función `cxoConnection_isConnected()` se ocupa de generar una excepción si no hay conexión y por eso la función que la llamó puede retornar `NULL` para indicar este hecho.

Si la conexión existe, entonces se llama a `dpiConn_ping()`, que no es parte ya de `cx_Oracle`, sino de otra biblioteca (también en C, pero sin interfaz Python) que `cx_Oracle` utiliza. Esta función, en caso de error, retorna un `status` negativo y pone un código de error en cierta variable global (similar a `errno`). El código arriba mostrado chequea esta condición y en caso de error, usa la variable global que indica el error para crear una excepción python y retornar NULL.

En resumen, tenemos el siguiente comportamiento:

- Si la conexión no está viva, se genera una excepción implícita (y `cxoConnection_isConnected()` se ocupa de ello).
- Si la conexión está viva pero el ping falla por alguna otra razón, se genera otra excepción (cuál en concreto es difícil de obtener, pues depende de lo que haga `dpiConn_ping()` que no es parte de este paquete).
- Si lo anterior ha ido bien, se retorna `None`.

Para completar el puzzle podemos ver el código de `cxoConnection_isConnected()`, que está en la [línea 502 del mismo fichero](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/fc3450d48ad923cac781618dfd47431c9e1e34f6/src/cxoConnection.c#L502) y dice así:

```py
int cxoConnection_isConnected(cxoConnection *conn)
{
    if (!conn->handle) {
        cxoError_raiseFromString(cxoInterfaceErrorException, "not connected");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Esto es interesante. Vemos que la comprobación necesaria para saber si la conexión está abierta es simplemente mirar que `conn->handle` sea distinto de cero. En caso contrario vemos que se genera la excepción `cxoInterfaceErrorException` (que dará lugar a la excepción Python `InterfaceError`) y con el *string* asociado `"not connected"`.

### Conclusión

Aunque el objeto `connection` accesible desde python tiene también un campo `handle`, según comentarios del usuario, parece que su única función es mantener el entero que representa internamente la conexión, que no cambia si ésta se cierra. Mi hipótesis es que el `handle` del código C vale cero sólo si la conexión aún no se ha iniciado o ha sido cerrada de forma explícita. No sirve por tanto para saber si la conexión sigue viva.

La solución por tanto es llamar a `connection.ping()` y si al hacerlo se genera una excepción, será que el ping ha fallado. Si todo lo que necesitamos es conocer si la conexión está viva o no, no necesitamos distinguir entre las diferentes excepciones que podría generar `ping()`. Cualquiera indicaría un problema en la conexión.

Si no se generan exepciones podemos asumir que la conexión goza de buena salud (e ignorar el `None` retornado por el `ping()`).